# Spring Boot MockMvc escapes dots from URL

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

If I make:

```
@Autowired
protected MockMvc mockMvc;

mockMvc.perform(delete("/example/test@email.com");
```

Controller gets test@email instead of test@email.com. How to pass URL with dot to `MockMvc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend your Controllers Method to accept dots.

E.g. you can write it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{email:.*}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```